# In the context of django-rest-framework is the Web API different from the actual website?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been looking into django-rest-framework.

Tell me if my impressions are correct.

It is meant to help you create restful API endpoints for your web app.

It is NOT meant to generate your actual website. The class-based views included in rest_framework (APIView, generics.ListCreateAPIView, etc) are not supposed to be used to render to web pages themselves.

So does this mean you are supposed to have one set of urls for this api and another set for accessing and navigating the website?

Comment: actually a very important question and worth it to make this explicit to newbies like myself.  So much communication is done via RESTful services these days, that it's easy to forget that the 'within' Django stuff is handled by the class-based views or function based views, and the Django-to-the-outside world communication is where the RESTful service is used.  Typical example for the RESTful API is going to be a mobile client, e.g. a NATIVE app for iPhone or Samsung Galaxy S4 trying to access your site

Comment: You can generate contents of your actual website based on templates in Django REST framework. Here is how to do it according to the official documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is meant to help you create restful API endpoints for your web app.

yes

> It is NOT meant to generate your actual website. The class-based views included in rest_framework (APIView, generics.ListCreateAPIView, etc) are not supposed to be used to render to web pages themselves.

yes

> So does this mean you are supposed to have one set of urls for this api and another set for accessing and navigating the website?

exactly

Comment: Are you duplicating a whole bunch of code this way? I was trying to start with rest-framework and combine the webpage/template-rendering into those views. It was just inconvenient enough that I thought I was doing something wrong, but really much of it is the same. Fetch the object, then either serialize and return json or get template context and return template response.

Comment: @JeffWong well, it really takes some extra coding. You can use class-based views to make it simple and DRY

Comment: ok, thanks. Last question: do you use these api endpoints in your ajax calls?

Comment: @JeffWong yes, on my project I do