# Django REST framework - views serving both regular webpages and API responses depending on the request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a web site using Django REST framework. This is my first days with the REST, so please bear with me. Basically, the question is,

1. Can I come up with a class-based view which could serve both as an API for Android developers (with JSON response) and a view rendering regular Django template? Or I have to define two different views for this purpose ?
2. If the answer to question 1 is that I have to define two separate views, then what is the most DRY method to do that taking into account that the querysets are the same ?

The view:

```
class TestList(APIView):
        renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
        template_name = 'android/test.html'

        def get(self, request):
            queryset = Test.objects.all()
            return Response({'test_qs': queryset})
```

Put in other words, imagine that I have a model queryset, I want to both render this on my site to my end user, and to send it to my Android developers. What is the best practice in terms of REST framework code architecture? Two different class based views? Or one view with two methods inside it ? Or one view with one magic method which would do both jobs for me ?

Comment: Although asked from a different perspective, but still relevant question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300971/in-the-context-of-django-rest-framework-is-the-web-api-different-from-the-actual?rq=1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300971/in-the-context-of-django-rest-framework-is-the-web-api-different-from-the-actual?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to keep it separate. With simple CRUD - you will not have the issues with DRY because they are simply different views, consider:

DRF (basically this is all for CRUD, if you want only a list use: ListModelMixin):

```
class ServiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
```

I think that merging this into one View - sooner or later will get you into troubles.

What kind of troubles?

- Your templates can at some point use much more data to display the page to the user than your REST API (simple example: current time) - you will start to implement different context for template and different for REST;
- and nothing more came to my mind ;) but I have a feeling that two separate views make it much more clean.

I also understand the risk of repeating the same code twice - but you can always extract the repeating code to some helping structures.

As for queryset - if it's simple - do not bother with one place for storing it. If it can get complicated - again - there's no problem to store the queryset in some helping structure and use in both views:

```
class ProjectQuerysets(object):
    my_test_qs = Test.objects.filter(created_at__gte=now-timedelta(seconds=30)).all()
```

or event something more sophisticated:

```
class TestQSMixni(object):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return Test.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)  # something like that;
```

And later:

```
class TestList(TestQSMixin, APIView):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

# and in REST:

class ServiceViewSet(TestQSMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ServicesSerializer
    # no queryset needed here
```

(sorry for example with this services, but I have this in some notes :))

Hope this will help you a little.

At the end - it all depends on your needs :) And the project requirements.

Happy coding.

Comment: I feel very much like accepting the answer. Merely because of lack of experience, I can't put together what you said. Could you please provide the skeleton of the view for regular template and the view for REST? Are they COMPLETELY independent, or do they share some common part? I would very much appreciate this

Comment: preferably extending or modifying the example that I mentioned in the question